# Code should return min value but it doesn't

Tags: python, django, model, min

I have a django app (1.8)
Here is part of my model:

```
price_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, null=True, help_text='price_1')
price_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, null=True, help_text='price_2')
price_3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, null=True, help_text='price_3')
price_4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, null=True, help_text='price_4')
price_5 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, null=True, help_text='price_5')
price_6 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, null=True, help_text='price_6')
price_7 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, null=True, help_text='price_7')
```

Here is my method in model:

```
def min_prices(self):
    prices = [self.price_1, self.price_2, self.price_3, self.price_4, self.price_5, self.price_6, self.price_7]
    return min(['{0}'.format(i) for i in prices if i is not None])
```

My values in model:

```
price 1: 4000
price 2: 2800
price 3: 1800
price 4: 900
```

My code should return 900 but I got 1800 and I do not get why.

Comment: With `'{0}'.format(i)` you convert your integers into strings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `min` function is comparing strings rather than numbers and so returning the smallest alphabetically.

Try:

```
return str(min([price for price in prices if price]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert strings to integers:

```
>>> prices = [4000, 2800, 1800, 900]
>>> min(['{0}'.format(i) for i in prices if i is not None])
'1800'
>>> min([int('{0}'.format(i)) for i in prices if i is not None])
900
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
>>> prices = [4000, 2000, 1800,900]

>>> '{}'.format(min(prices))

'900'
```

Comment: Whilst its great that it works for you... this doesn't explain what issue the op is having